# Adding some basic layer of security to the app.config file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, connection-string, app-config

Lately I've been a bit concerned with the security of my WPF app. I'm just starting out so security hasn't been my main focus but now I'm a bit worried that someone might open the *.exe.config* file in the Programs folder and use the credentials there. The people using this basic CRUD app wouldn't probably know what to do with it even if they get to it but I don't want to take any chances.

I am just looking for the easiest way to hide it somehow, either by using an external config file or encrypt it. I've tried every possible answer on stackoverflow but I just could find a straightforward way of doing it.

Here's what I what my app.config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c666935e080" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DailyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Model.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xx.xxx.xx.xx,port;initial catalog=MyDB;user id=testsubject;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Here's what I have already tried:
[Protect App.Config file or Encrypt](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3b5a1d1f-aa57-40d8-8607-fee0b2a8a6db/protect-appconfig-file-or-encrypt)

The problem that I have with this is that it encrypts the file and it works great on my machine but I cannot deploy in on another machine.

and 
[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)

Can someone help with some simple, dumbed-down advice/example? I don't want to use Windows Authentication or write a whole lot of code just to achieve this. Just something to make it a little harder to get the credentials.

Comment: imo any sort of confidential information on the client side is bad, and especially so in .net. Any reason why you are directly accessing a database via IP? could this not be put behind a webapi of some sort?

Comment: Encrypting your credentials might slow down attackers, but it will never be "secure" because if the application itself can decrypt it, so can an attacker. Normally you wouldn't connect to an SQL server from the client machine, you would have a service instead. But if you have to use a direct connection you could always leave out the user and password from the connection string and display a login form to the user where they have to type in the credentials everytime they launch the application.

Comment: @AppPack I agree, it might not be the best practice but I am just trying to keep things as simple a possible. To be honest I do not have enough knowledge to do that.

Comment: @Wazner Thank you for you clear explanation. I am pretty certain that there won't be any attackers, I just don't want it to make it so it isn't that easily available. I am jsut trying to gather some information from the users and make it as easu as possible which is why I don't want to set up login to access the app. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: This is presumably used in a small company by just a few guys on desktops and the data is relatively low sensitivity. If it's just CRUD then you could give the user you have on there just minimal security privileges in sql server and reduce the risk of anyone dropping a table. If you had active directory then changing to trusted would be best though and allocate minimal privileges to whatever AD group your users are in.

Comment: @Andy Thank you for you advice! I think this might be the best approach and I'll end up doing that. The user has minimal security privileges and I'll look into AD as well.

Comment: @Andy Can you please show me how can I add an external config file that gets referenced in the app.config file on top of that? I think that would be the solution to my problem.

Comment: I can't really see the point if you use windows id based security. All you would be giving away in the app.config is the ip address and database name.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: you can't - nothing you put in your WPF code can ever be secure.

Sure, you could take steps like encoding the values in the config file, and then having your code decrypt them.  Problem is, a potential attacker could simply dump your app into a decompiler (like DotPeek) and see exactly what your decryption method is.  Basically, the only people that it'll stop are the ones that are least dangerous to have breaking into your system.

Generally, you want to put a layer between the app and the DB, so that an attacker disassembling your WPF app doesn't have a raw connection to the database.  That way, instead of an attacker having a portal directly into the database, they've simply got the address of a WebService.  Worst case, they start try calling WebService ABC themselves - but that's a heck of a lot better than them having straight DB access.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks for the straight answer. I am aware that someone could use a decompiler but I wouldn't worry about that. The few people using it to input some data have no idea what a decompiler is. I am not looking to make it bullet proof, just not to have the string so easily available. It's just a basic tool that we use internally. I will look into the WebService approach and perhaps use it in future projects but for now I'm just looking at the easiest way to tackle this. Do you think you could provide an example? Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't dismiss decompiling so lightly.  It used to be that it was a very difficult task (with apps decompiling into assembly and it requiring a very dedicated and proficient person to be able to do it.)  Nowadays, all you have to do is drag an '.exe' file onto DotPeek, and it'll show you straight-up .NET code.  If someone knows any programming at all, they'll be able to decompile a .NET app with minimal trouble.

Comment: You are right @Kevin. It this particular case these guys don't know any programming at all. I almost feel comfortable leaving it as it is.

Comment: As for specific hurdles you could throw?  Unfortunately, I'm not an expert on entity framework, but I'd look in to see whether you can manipulate the ConnectionString at runtime, and add a pepper to the password that's stored in the config file.  (Basically, whatever the config file says the password is, add "c^3-[8dV" to the end of it.)

Comment: Thanks for your time and advice. Sounds like a good approach, I'll look into it.

Comment: Ugh.  iCosmin, I'd bet that half the security breaches through the last decade or two were because of a programmer saying, "Eh, nobody will know enough to exploit this hole; no need to worry about making it secure."  Even if you don't think your users are savvy enough *now* to exploit it, what about new hires down the road?  Or for that matter, is there any possibility of a programmer getting access to the .exe file at all?  Because I can tell you, a lot of security-conscious programmers will decompile apps for the heck of it (usually because they're white-hats, but sometimes they're not...)

Comment: I are precisely right and that's how I think in most cases. The reason my I am at ease is that a) even if someone gets to login into server, there isn't any valuable information there - it's kept on a different db and b)it's just a temporary tool to gather some info for internal use so I will end up scrapping it at one point. I wish I had a tutorial on how to do the Webservice thing without having to spend a few days on it. Do you know a good guide that could help in this particular case?

Comment: How I'd usually do this sort of thing would be with web api as rest services. You have a method per call essentially and that is decorated with an attribute defines the server routing. If you have a number of tables and database calls then this could be a fair bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say that it is absolutely ridiculous and makes no sense that Microsoft would provide automatic encryption for Web.config files in ASP.Net but *not* in WPF / Desktop applications?

Seriously Microsoft? There is basically no good answer

Comment: This should be a comment.